# Running a JavaFX from cmd

Tags: java, javafx

How can I make a .jar file from my JavaFX program without having to tell the computer where the modules are located:

```
javaw --module-path c:\devel\javafx\lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar myProgram.jar
```

Let's say for example, that I wish to send the program to my friend, who doesn't have JavaFX libraries on his/her computer.
I just wanto make it work so, that when you write:

```
java -jar myProgram.jar
```

It opens

Comment: See the section in the [openjfx.io docs](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) titled "Runtime Images" "Cross-platform jar".  Perhaps that will help you find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why not go the full way and create a real platform installer as you would do it with any other software? Have a look at this tutorial which I co-authored (so I am biased): https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX